# How to Jackson Serialize/Deserialize Bill-of-Materials Entities

Tags: java, jackson

My database has a number of bill-of-materials structures, including one that defines relationships between parties:

[image: Party-Relationship Logical Model]

The 1st interactor tends to play the senior role - e.g. employer - and the 2nd interactor the minor role - e.g. employee.

I would like to be able to serialize this to JSON but I'm hitting problems.

My entities are annotated like this:

**Party**

```
@OneToMany(
    targetEntity = PartyRelationshipDO.class,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
@JoinColumn(name = "first_party_id", referencedColumnName = "party_id")
@JsonProperty("firstParties")
@JsonManagedReference(value = "FirstParty")
private Set<PartyRelationshipDO> firstParties;

@OneToMany(
    targetEntity = PartyRelationshipDO.class,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
@JoinColumn(name = "second_party_id", referencedColumnName = "party_id")
@JsonProperty("secondParties")
@JsonManagedReference(value = "SecondParty")
private Set<PartyRelationshipDO> secondParties;
```

**PartyRelationship**

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "first_party_id", referencedColumnName = "party_id")
@JsonProperty("firstParty")
@JsonBackReference(value = "FirstParty")
private PartyDO firstParty;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "second_party_id", referencedColumnName = "party_id")
@JsonProperty("secondParty")
@JsonBackReference(value = "SecondParty")
private PartyDO secondParty;
```

This works *up to a point*. When I serialise my test case I get:

```
{
    "partyId": 1,
    "partyIdentifier": "first.interactor@email.address",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "partyIdentifierType": {
        "typeKey": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
    },
    "secondParties": [
        {
            "effectivePeriodFrom": "2021-11-01T15:55:38.518Z",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "firstPartyId": 1,
            "secondPartyId": 2
        }
    ],
    "firstName": "First",
    "lastName": "Interactor"
}
```

The trouble is, the `secondParty` object is not serialized in the `"secondParties"` array. What I'd like to see is:

```
{
    "partyId": 1,
    "partyIdentifier": "first.interactor@email.address",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "partyIdentifierType": {
        "typeKey": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
    },
    "secondParties": [
        {
            "effectivePeriodFrom": "2021-11-01T15:55:38.518Z",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "firstPartyId": 1,
            "secondPartyId": 2,
            "secondParty": {
                "partyId": 2,
                "partyIdentifier": "second.interactor@email.address",
                "isDeleted": false,
                "partyIdentifierType": {
                    "typeKey": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
                },
                "firstName": "Second",
                "lastName": "Interactor"
            }
        }
    ],
    "firstName": "First",
    "lastName": "Interactor"
}
```

If I *don't* use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`, I get a `StackOverflowError` with this chunk of stacktrace being repeated:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.PersistentCollectionSerializer.serialize(PersistentCollectionSerializer.java:243)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
```

I understand that Bill-of-Materials structures are recursive by their very nature, but I'm only interested in going up/down one level. So, as the *1st Interactor*, list all my *2nd Interactors*, or as a *2nd Interactor*, list all my *1st Interactors*.

How is this achieved?

Comment: Using your domain objects (spring entities) as DTOs is not a great idea as it ties your domain to whatever API you have created. Rather than fix the problem you have you might want to create a set of objects that can be used for the API independently of your domain model.

Comment: I certainly plan on using views at the API level, but I also need to share this domain model via message queues in a technology neutral way - ie JSON / XML.

Comment: I think I've found the answer in the class level annotation `@JsonIdentityInfo`, as in: `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")`. I'll need to do some more test cases to be sure.